# How to efficiently check stored procedure for existence in PHP

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am trying to create procedures from PHP, in my dbConnect.php file, which is there to provide access to my database. This file is included in every file that needs database access. Unfortunately, that means that stored procedures that have been already created cause the code to throw errors (because it is trying to create stored procedures that already exist).

I have tried looking [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php) for help on stored procedures, as well as combing the internet for anything that will help with the creation of stored procedures, but all I can manage to find are examples where they delete the stored procedure if it is already created. That seems like a huge waste, because there is some potentially expensive methods being invoked **every time database access is needed**.

I am trying to, instead of drop-and-recreate, just check for existence and if it does not exist, create it. In other words, I would like to do something like the following:

```
$storedProcedureExists = $connection->query(/* some query that checks for the existence of that stored procedure */);
if (!$storedProcedureExists)
{
     // create the stored procedure here
}
```

Comment: I would like to know the query that checks for the existence of the stored procedure in the database

Comment: Why don't you just create the procedures once as part of setting up the database, and just assume that they'll always be there for your scripts, just like you assume that the tables are already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to determine if a procedure exists:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS found
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_schema = 'yourDBname'
AND routine_name = 'yourProcedureName'
```

If `$row['found']` is `1` then the procedure already exists, if it's `0` it doesn't exist.

Comment: Where is the array `$row`?

Comment: It's just a placeholder for whatever variable you use when you call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` from that query.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures are queryable in the [ROUTINES table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/routines-table.html) of the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html).

You could use this query to find the stored procedure names in your database, assuming your database name is `dbname` and your procedure name is `procname`:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE="PROCEDURE"
  AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA="dbname"
  AND ROUTINE_NAME="procname"
```

Comment: This works from the phpMyAdmin side of things, but for some reason fails every time from the PHP side of things.